# Chrome - onclick and href at the same time

Tags: html, google-chrome, onclick, href

This works fine in IE and FIREFOX. I just can't get it to work right in CHROME.

What I want to happen when the link is clicked, to launch the local mail client and then change the page to google.

In chrome, if I use the tag below it will launch the local mail client, but it won't change the page to Google.

```
<a href="mailto:?subject=hi" OnClick="window.location.href='http://www.google.com/'">Launch outlook and google</a>
```

If I add "return false" on the end as seen below, it will change the page to google, but it won't launch the local mail client.

```
 <a href="mailto:?subject=hi" OnClick="window.location.href='http://www.google.com/';return false;">Launch outlook and google</a>
```

How do I get this to work in CHROME like it does in IE and FIREFOX?

Answer (score 2):

`javascript:` makes no sense in `onclick` and is syntactically incorrect.  You should actually bind the event with JavaScript using `addEventListener`, but if you must use onclick, just

```
window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com/'
```

Should be enough.  Also, why the `return false`?  That would stop the default event which is the opening of the mail client, right?

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and edited my original question, I still get the same results.